# onclick="window.open()" solo me funciona en uno de los 4 botones

Tags: html, onclick

Tengo 4 botones a los que que quiero enlazar un html cada uno, y que se abran en pestaña nueva.

```
    <div class="boton">
        <button onclick="window.open('sobre_mi.html')">Sobre mi</button>
    </div>
    <div class="boton">
        <button onclick="window.open('habilidades.html')">Habilidades</button>
    </div>
    <div class="boton">
        <button onclick="window.open('proyectos.html')">Proyectos</button>
    </div>
     <div class="boton">
        <button onclick="window.open('contacto.html')">Contacto</button>
    </div>
```

Bueno, pues solo funciona el primero. Alguien sabe por qué?

Comment: A mi se me abren los cuatro, cada uno con su pestañita

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me permito señalar que estás implementando una práctica no recomendada<sup>1</sup>, que consiste en poner funciones *in-line* dentro de los elementos HTML.

Esto dificulta el mantenimiento del código, por ejemplo, en programas grandes, donde tengas muchos HTML diseminados, si necesitaras cambiar algo tendrás que buscar/editar todos esos HTML.

Puedes aplicar la separación de código para este caso alcanzando todos los botones con la clase `boton` mediante [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), luego asignas un listener a los clicks de todos esos elementos y dentro de ese listener lanzas el `window.open`. Puedes usar la propiedad `value` de cada botón para indicar la URL a la que se debe navegar.

Aplicando esto el HTML quedaría así (observa que las llamadas *in line* ya no están):

```
<div class="boton">
    <button value="sobre_mi.html">Sobre mi</button>
</div>
<div class="boton">
    <button value="habilidades.html">Habilidades</button>
</div>
<div class="boton">
    <button value="proyectos.html">Proyectos</button>
</div>
 <div class="boton">
    <button value="contacto.html">Contacto</button>
</div>
```

Y en Javascript:

```
//Todos los button en los div con la clase boton
var allButtons = document.querySelectorAll('div.boton > button');

//Asignamos el listener
allButtons.forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var theURL=e.target.value;
    window.open(theURL,theURL.replace(".html", ""));
    });
});
```

---

#### Fiddle

Aquí puedes ver un <kbd>[**`FIDDLE`**](https://jsfiddle.net/acedano/8m9suorp/1/)</kbd> completo.

---

#### Notas

1. Leer al respecto el apartado [*Separation of structure and behaviour* (*Separación de estructura y comportamiento*)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), en w3.org

Answer (score 1):

Primero que nada te recomiendo que le asignes un ID a cada botón

```
<button id="aboutme" onclick="window.open('sobre_mi.html')">Sobre mi</button>
```

y revisa si no te arroja algún error de ejecución en el inspector del navegador, sería bueno que nos compartieras que botón no funciona y el código de la referencia que debería abrir
te dejo un código a ver si te sirve:

```
<a href="AntSdoNeg.asp?Usr=<%=Usuario%>" target="_blank" onclick="window.open(this.href, this.target, 'width=1100,height=500,top=50,left=100'); return false;">Antigüedad de Saldos por Negocio</a></li>
```

el código es solo para que te des un ejemplo, no lo implementes tal cual por que usa VBScript.

Comment: Genial, no se que ha pasado pero solo he quitado div que no usaba para nada y he puesto **id** como indicabas y al refrescar funciona.  Genial, muchas gracias